# Why process limits are tied to signals in Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

Is there any reason why process limits (`struct rlimit rlim[RLIM_NLIMITS]`) are located within `signal_struct` structure of process descriptor (`struct task_struct`) in Linux Kernel?